# How to get notification if new user register in local SQL database in android

Tags: android, database, notifications

i want call this function if a new user register in database , when a new row created in db broadcast receiver check and call this function.

```
 public void notification(){

        NotificationCompat.Builder notify=(NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setDefaults(NotificationCompat.DEFAULT_ALL)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.logo))
                .setContentTitle("New Notification")
                .setContentText("Click here to View");
        NotificationManager notifyMang=(NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notifyMang.notify(1,notify.build());
    }
```

if a new User register in database call this function.

Comment: local db? you mean SQLite on your android ?

Comment: yes localhost like xammp , wampp, SQLite too but i am using wampp

Comment: why you need notification if the user register in the local DB.?

Comment: Actually i am submitting a leave application through form in android, if a user submit a leave application admin receive a notification.

Comment: you can have observer patter that observe your change in database and notify you that db has some change from that callback i guess you can get notification.use viewmodel architecture for same.

Comment: i used this function in a button when i click button it shows demo notification but i need if a user table update then i receive a notification? am i right ? You got it?

Comment: i think here use broadcast receiver but don't know how to use...